# Python: How can I delete an item from a list to be selected as an input in the program?

Tags: python, list, input

```
Tasks = []

while True:
    linea1 = raw_input("Add, remove or print task ").split()
    if not linea1:
        break;

    AddTask = str (linea1[0])
    if linea1[0] == "add_task":
        Tasks.append(linea1)
    elif linea1[0] == "remove_task":
        del (Tasks[x])
    elif linea1[0] == "view_tasks":
        for index in range(len(Tasks)):  
            print("[{}] : {}".format(index, Tasks[index]))
    else:
        break;
```

Add, remove or print task remove_task

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list

Comment: The first bit is code too, didn't appear correctly in the question

Comment: what is `x` in your code ?

Comment: You don't need semi-colons for one thing. Did you come from any of the C languages, or Java?

Comment: `Tasks.append(linea1)` ... why would you want your tasks to contain a list containing the string `'add_task'`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question sounds like a homework question, and SO is not a homework writing service; see [help], and [tour].

Comment: Yeah, SO is only for doing your homework once you have a job ;)

Answer (score 0):

You want remove_task to remove the last element? If so you just need a small modification like so:

```
Tasks = []

while True:
    linea1 = raw_input("Add, remove or print task ").split()
    if not linea1:
        break;

    AddTask = str (linea1[0])
    if linea1[0] == "add_task":
        Tasks.append(linea1)
    elif linea1[0] == "remove_task":
        del (Tasks[len(Tasks) - 1])
    elif linea1[0] == "view_tasks":
        for index in range(len(Tasks)):  
            print("[{}] : {}".format(index, Tasks[index]))
    else:
        break;
```